# How to test a custom form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to write a test for my custom form helper.
Following the instructions from [Custom form helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623250/custom-form-helpers), I have a form helper like this:

```
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper

  def smile_tag(method, options = {})
    ...
  end
end
```

How would you write a test for smile_tag?

```
class MyHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test "smile_tag" do
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to myself...

I've found a project on GitHub where the developer creates form helpers and tests them.
https://github.com/dabit/bootstrap-form (it is a gem for Bootstrap Twitter, the project has not seen changes in months).