# How to modify the HTML generated by Rails form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I want to get this structure:

```
<label for="form-field-1" class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Text Field</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <div class="input string optional url_command_model_name"><input type="text" name="url_command[model_name]" id="url_command_model_name" class="string optional"></div>
</div>
```

But when I use `= f.input :model_name`, I get this HTML:

```
<div class="input string optional url_command_model_name">
  <label for="url_command_model_name" class="string optional control-label">Model name</label>
  <input type="text" name="url_command[model_name]" id="url_command_model_name" class="string optional">
</div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest not to fight with form helpers and using a good old input_tag

Comment: If you're going to want to re-use this structure for forms a lot then you could make your own form helpers.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623250/custom-form-helpers

Comment: Alternatively, make a partial, or do as @apneadiving suggests and just have the raw html in your template, plugging in the dynamic data as necessary.