# Rails: How to implement Action Text in Rails 5.2.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, trix

I'm experiencing difficulties in implementing the [Action Text gem](https://github.com/rails/actiontext) to my **Rails 5.2.1** application.

I followed the installation guide and the rich text editor wouldn't show up in my _form view.

I then realised that it requires **Rails 6** with **webpacker** and **active storage**. Changing my gemfile's Rails version and running *rails upgrade* didn't work, so I added the webpacker and active storage gems and bundled it with my current 5.2.1 version. That didn't work either.

I'd really like to have a Rich Text Editor in my app. It is not a must that it is the Trix editor, but since it will be native as of v6 I thought it was the obvious choice.

References of my source code

- GitHub: https://github.com/Curting/mydanceplan
- Heroku: https://mydanceplan.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The perfect choice ,tested on my new application using rails 5.2.3 .
please not action text require ruby 2.5.3 up. 
first : Add webpacker

You can either add Webpacker during setup of a new Rails 5.1+ application using new --webpack option:

## Available Rails 5.1+

```
rails new myapp --webpack
```

Or add it to your Gemfile:

## Gemfile

```
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.x'
```

## OR if you prefer to use master

```
gem 'webpacker', git: 'https://github.com/rails/webpacker.git'
yarn add https://github.com/rails/webpacker.git
```

Now add Actiontext to your gem file with image magic:

```
gem'actiontext',github:'kobaltz/actiontext',branch:'archive',require:'action_text'
gem 'image_processing'
```

Finally, run the following to install Webpacker:

```
bundle
bundle exec rails webpacker:install

rails action_text:install
rails db:migrate
brew install imagemagick vips
```

add this to your view/layout/application  in the head section

```
#layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

In your model , it may be an article or what ever in your model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :content
end
```

in your controller

```
 #controllers/articles_controller.rb
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:name, :content)
    end
```

in your form

```
#_form.html.erb
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :content %>
  <%= form.rich_text_area :content %>
</div>
```

finaly to display the content in your view;

```
<h1><%= @article.name %></h1>
<p><%= @article.content %></p>
```

Optional: To fix "unmet peer dependency" warnings,

```
yarn upgrade
```

you can watch the full video here: 
https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/using-action-text-in-a-rails-5-2-application

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer for you!  I wanted to use Trix, Rails 5.2.2, and Webpacker, but couldn't find a clear answer.  The trix gem didn't work since I don't use the asset pipeline at all.  (I also use Turbolinks and Stimulus, and so far this is working fine alongside those.)

I strung a solution together using:

- [trix node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trix)
- a custom form tag helper, derived from [this Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623250/custom-form-helpers)

I can now use a form helper that looks like this (using the Slim templating language):

```
= f.trix :personal_notes, class: 'some-css-class'
```

To get there, I did the following:

1. `yarn add trix`
2. In my Javascript pack, `import 'trix';`
3. In my CSS pack, `@import '~trix/dist/trix';`
4. Then I created the form helper.  Here's what that looked like:

In `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`, I added the new form helper, based on that Stack post I linked above.  My file now looks like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    # ...

    class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
        # include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper # I didn't need this.
        include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
        include ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper
        # include ActionView::Helpers::CaptureHelper  # I didn't need this.
        # include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper  # I didn't need this.

        # since these tag helpers just return strings, it is easy to make a pretty 
        # powerful helper.  It is probably possible to use existing Rails form 
        # helpers to aid this as well.
        def trix(method, options = {})
          value = (@object[method].empty?) ? '' : "value='#{@object[method]}'" 
          return "<input id='#{field_id(method)}' type='hidden' name='#{field_name(method)}' #{value}><trix-editor input='#{field_id(method)}' class='trix-content #{options[:class]}'></trix-editor>".html_safe
        end

        def field_name(label,index=nil)
          return @object_name + "[#{label}]"
        end

        def field_id(label,index=nil)
          return @object_name + "_#{label}"
        end

    end
end
```

Restart Rails.  Seems to work for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mungojerie. I'll definitely consider that. Can I ask you why you've chosen not to use the asset pipeline?

Comment: In part because Rails is moving towards webpack, and in part because I'm used to it, in part because of hot module reloading.  So given that, using JUST webpack is much easier for my brain... all JS, CSS, and images handled by one process.